# How do I correctly style a component in fluent UI/React/ts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluentui-react

I am trying to add a background color to this div:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Itest } from '../../../../../models'
import { getPreviewStyles } from './preview.style.ts'

type IPreviewProps = Itest

const PreviewC: React.FunctionComponent<IPreviewProps> = (props: IPreviewProps) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="base">test test</h1>
      <p>testing testing</p>
      <img src="workingAtComputer.jpg"></img>
    </div>
  )
}

export const Preview = PreviewC
```

Here I am trying to add a background color of purple:

```
import { IStyle } from 'office-ui-fabric-react'

export interface IPreviewStyles {
  base: IStyle
}

export const getPreviewStyles = (): IPreviewStyles => {
  return {
    base: {
      backgroundColor: 'purple',
    }
}
```

I get this error in the first file: "'getPreviewStyles' is declared but its value is never read." How can I have the styling applied to the div with className "base"? Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to implement `css-in-js` but for that you need to use `Merge styles` which comes along side with `Office Fabric UI` or `FluentUI` as newer version.

Preview.style.ts:

```js
import { mergeStyleSets } from '@fluentui/merge-styles';

export interface IPreviewStyles {
  base: string;
}

export const getPreviewStyles = (): IPreviewStyles => {
  return mergeStyleSets({
    base: {
      background: 'purple',
    },
  });
};
```

Component:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Itest } from '../../../../../models'
import { getPreviewStyles } from './preview.style.ts'

type IPreviewProps = Itest

const PreviewC: React.FunctionComponent<IPreviewProps> = (props: IPreviewProps) => {

  const { base } = getPreviewStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={base}>test test</h1>
      <p>testing testing</p>
      <img src="workingAtComputer.jpg"></img>
    </div>
  )
}

export const Preview = PreviewC
```

You can read more about Merge styles API [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/master/packages/merge-styles). And my recommendation for you is to switch on latest version of [FluentUI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/get-started/web).

Comment: Your assistance was much appreciated. I was going in circles. Thank you so much!